# Excel VBA, Add "Yes" to adjacent cells if corresponding value on other sheet says "Create"

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a sheet called "Batch records" using data from the original sheet, "35.s". In column A of 35.s, I have integer values that range from A1 to A414, and in column B of 35.s, I have text that says either "CREATE", "WAIT" or is blank. 
I want to create a sheet called Batch records that copies column A from 35.s, but now is column B, I want a true or false of whether the text from column B says "CREATE"  or not.

[An Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbN9u.png)

Comment: In the column adjacent to what? Throughout, which columns are we comparing? Some sample data and expected output would go a long way  in clarifying this question I think. And what have you tried so far? Please share the code.

Comment: In 35.s I have two columns A and B. Column A has integer values and B has text.
In Batch Records, column A has the same integer values. I need to plan out how to write a Macro that will determine a true or false of whether the text in 35.s column B says "CREATE" or not and transfer that to Batch records column B as "Yes" or "No".

Comment: I think showing some sample data and expected output would help. Why  offset (-1,0)? Are you looping backwards from H414 to H1 or something similar?

Comment: please [edit] additional info into your question. It will increase the chances of a faster answer.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information about the role of column H and why the offset of -1 here is a simple way of achieving what you described in the comments using the same range in B as you describe for H.

It uses Index and Match to find pairs and return the adjacent value which is tested for ="Create" leading to either "Yes" or "No" output. In the case of no match found "" is returned.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub AddFormulas()

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Batch Records").Range("B1:B414").FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(IF(INDEX(' 35.s'!R1C2:R4C2,MATCH(RC[-1],' 35.s'!R1C1:R4C1,0))=""CREATE"",""YES"",""NO""),"""")"
End Sub
```